# How can I use Metamask RPC API to build an Ethereum miner?

Tags: ethereum, rpc, cryptocurrency, metamask, mining

I am tring to build an Ethereum miner using Metamask RPC. I saw eth_getWork and eth_submitWork methods, but I can't use them because I need to connect as a miner first. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send login request, example:

```
{"id": 1,"jsonrpc": "2.0","method": "eth_submitLogin","params": ["0xblablalba"]}
```